# Categorizing a hash of arrays into a datatable. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable

I'm not sure how to go about categorizing a hash of arrays. My hash would look something like this:

```
{"Level 1" => [foo, bar], "Level 2" => [foo, bar, foobar]}
```

I want to be able to display the hash key in a row, and then place the objects of that keys value in rows below that.

Heres an example of how the view should look:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can just call `flatten` twice.

```
myhash = {"Level 1" => ["foo", "bar"], "Level 2" => ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]}  

myhash.flatten.flatten
=> ["Level 1", "foo", "bar", "Level 2", "foo", "bar", "foobar"]
```